# Make container covariant

Tags: c++

I am implementing a custom vector of pointers `my_ptr_vector`.

I have a class `Base` and a `Derived` deriving `Base`.

I have a method which should act (by const reference!) on both `my_ptr_vector<Base>` and `my_ptr_vector<Derived>`. It only invokes on the elements methods from the `Base` class of course.

However, the compiler complains it has no way of converting `my_ptr_vector<Derived>` into `my_ptr_vector<Base>`.

Minimal example reproducing the issue:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};

template<typename Element>
class my_ptr_vector : public std::vector< std::unique_ptr< Element > > {};

void funct(const my_ptr_vector<Base>& vect) {}

int main()
{
    my_ptr_vector<Derived> vect;
    funct(vect);
}
```

error:

```
no suitable user-defined conversion from "my_ptr_vector<Derived>" to "const my_ptr_vector<Base>" exists
```

I have found [here](http://cpptruths.blogspot.com.mt/2015/11/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c.html) that I could make it work if I provided a constructor and assignment operator from a `my_ptr_vector<U>`, with `U` generic, such that `U*` can be converted to `T*`.

Indeed if in the example I change the class to this, it works

```
template<typename Element>
class my_ptr_vector : public std::vector< std::shared_ptr< Element > > {
public: 
    my_ptr_vector() {}

    ///copy constructor from vector of pointers to generic U
template<typename DerivedElement>
    my_ptr_vector(const my_ptr_vector<DerivedElement>& oth)
    {
        printf("Oh, noes!");  //we don't want this method executed!

        resize(oth.size());

        for (std::shared_ptr< Element > ptr : oth)
        {
            push_back(ptr);
        }
    }
};
```

However, it *does* execute the `print` statement in the constructor -it's not just a hint that it shouldn't worry; it is actually performing the conversion!

Is there a way to avoid this?

Another possible solution is of course to make `func` templated:

```
template<typename T>
    void funct(const my_ptr_vector<T>& vect) {}
```

However, in this way I lose the information that inside `func`, the elements of `vect` are always of type `Base`.

Comment: It's easier if you show us code ([mcve]).  My first thought is to use `my_ptr_vector<Base*>`, which is the usual way to handle vectors of classes some of which may be derived.

Comment: maybe you are looking for a good old [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)?

Comment: @TopologicalSort you're right, done :)

Comment: @W.F. that IS what I did in fact!

Comment: you can make your `funct` a template

Comment: @AndyT that is what I ended up doing at first :) However, in this way I lose the information that inside `func`, the elements of `vect` are always of type `Base`. There should be a better way.

Comment: @FrancescoDondi Well, compiler is right here - the `Base` and `Derived` classes are coupled with an inheritance hierarchy although your `my_ptr_vector` of `Derived` has nothing in common to `my_ptr_vector` of `Base` you cannot treat the former as a latter and the other way around.

Comment: @FrancescoDondi Maybe you could change your `funct` to have yet another template parameter - the base type if this way you wouldn't loose this information at any time you invoke it. The function could look: `template<class B, typename Actual> void funct(const my_ptr_vector<Actual>& vect)`. And the invocation: `funct<Base>(vect);`

Comment: @FrancescoDondi PS. without extended information of what is your use case of `funct` your question seems to be actually [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what you want.  The second part of the code, the copy ctor, didn't need to be altered.

I don't think you can get away from needing to cast to `std::unique_ptr`.  It wants that even if it's pushing a `Base*`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};

template<typename Element>
class my_ptr_vector : public std::vector< std::unique_ptr< Element > > {};

void funct(const my_ptr_vector<Base>& vect) {}

int main()
{
  my_ptr_vector<Base> vect;
  vect.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Base>(new Derived)); 

  funct(vect);
}
```

Comment: Yes this compiles; but I'd lose the possibility to call Derived-only methods, and I need that.

Comment: @FrancescoDondi no you wouldn't - this is what `dynamic_cast`/`static_cast` was made for...

Comment: Mhh yes you're right, but it's ugly. Rather than having to remember inside `func` that the type is `Base` and not `T`, I have to remember outside that the type is `Derived` not `Base`... what I want is to shift the type-checking onus on the compiler.

Comment: I'm not sure of the problem.  It might help to say what `funct` is for.  If it does things with `Base`s including `Derived`s, this will work.  If it's supposed to do something that will only apply to `Derived`s, replace `Base` with `Derived` in `funct` and `main` and you're good.

Comment: Say more about the "ugly," too.  The only place the code refers to `Derived` is when you create that class, and when you create an element of that type, and surely both are inevitable.  Is it something else?